# The whoomping willow continuity error

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

In the *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* movie, there is a scene between Newt & Leta in their Hogwarts years. There we can see the famous whoomping willow.

But according to Remus Lupin the willow was planted to guard the entrance to the shrieking shack. According to Harry Potter wikia, it was planted in 1971. Doesn't that create a continuity error in the wizarding universe?

Comment: I've not seen the movie, so I won't give an answer - but perhaps the 1971 tree was planted as a replacement for an older tree that had died?

Comment: If it’s a magic tree, why can’t it move location?

Comment: @Drai: By that logic Hogwarts was also movable. No, that's now how things work in magic world. :D

Comment: @Rahul what I mean is that the tree can move it’s limbs to “whomp” why couldn’t it move its roots and walk to a new location?

Comment: @Drai: That's what I am saying. So far Whomping Willow can move it's branches not roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had my suspicion and this article proves it right.

In *Chamber of Secrets* Whomping Willow was in training grounds. But in *Prizoner of Azkaban* it was on the hill outside Hogwarts.

And from [**Pottermore**](https://www.pottermore.com/features/behind-the-scenes-whomping-willow),

> In Prisoner of Azkaban, the Whomping Willow was moved from the training grounds to a hill outside Hogwarts, where it covered the entrance to the secret passageway that leads to the Shrieking Shack.

But since [**Harry Potter Wikia**](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Whomping_Willow) says it was planted in 1971 I think it's a mistake in writing.

Comment: So you're saying it's proberbly a continuity error.

Comment: @AsifIqubal: It might be. Unless there is another mention of someone planting it in training ground. BTW where was location of whomping willow in *Crimes of Grindelwald* ?